# Exchange manage rules for automatic replies

Tags: windows, exchange-2010

Outlook provides the ability to set rules for your Automatic Reply and we need an administrative way to alter this settings.
The Exchange Control Panel provides only the possibility to set
"Don't send automatic replies" and "Send automatic replies". There doesn't seem to be any Button for setting the rules.

The next try was the Exchange Management Shell via

```
Get-Mailbox SAMID | Get-MailboxAutoReplyConfiguration | fl
```

But it only provides the same information as the ECP without any rules.

Is there a way to see what rules are set inside automatic replies (espacially forwarding) and a way to alter them as an adminstrator?

We are using Exchange 2010 and Outlook 2007, 2010 and 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that the ECP only gives the ability to enable or disable the OOF (Out of Office) Assistant.  It won't let you modify or set any Automatic Reply Rules.

Same for the Exchange Management Shell as shown here:  [Control Out Of Office via the Exchange Shell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/4d55cc06-3426-475e-a6fc-4f04eeba36c7/control-out-of-office-via-the-exchange-shell)

The only way for an administer to alter or see what these rule sets are is to give an admin Full Access to a mailbox and then open that mailbox in Outlook via a separate mail profile.

It would be great if there were a shell command similar to `Get-InboxRule` such as `Get-AutoReplyRule` but there just isn't yet.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff381460.aspx shows how to grant Full Access to a Mailbox via EMC and PS code.